# Moving a line from one screen to other screen in vim

Tags: vim, split, screens

Suppose I have opened two different files in two vertical screens in vim. Is a there a single command to move the line under cursor to other screen?

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser or U&L since it's not really a programming question. Perhaps you should flag it for a moderator to migrate to the appropriate site.

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge. Delete it, switch panes and paste it.

```
dd<ctrl>ww</ctrl>p
```

Of course if this is something you do regularly you can write a macro for it, just like for any other sequence of commands in vim. For example to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to this function, you could run this in your buffer or set it in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:map <C-x> dd<C-w><C-w>p<C-w><C-w>
```

Comment: @Benj: I didn't see your version until I had posted my edit. I was off in another window working it up so I had the edit window open for a while and didn't see your post.

Comment: Haha no worries, mine was kind of based on your first bit anyway :-)

Comment: You don't need `:map` here (it defines mapping for too much modes and also depends on other mappings). Use `:nnoremap`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this on a regular basis, just map it to a keystroke. e.g.

```
map <C-A> dd<C-W><C-W>P<C-W><C-W>
```

Comment: Same as for Caleb above: you should not use `:map` here.